# How to animate borderColor change in swift

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

For some reason this isn't working for me:

```
let color = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
color.fromValue = sender.layer.borderColor;
color.toValue = UIColor.redColor().CGColor;
color.duration = 2;
color.repeatCount = 1;
sender.layer.addAnimation(color, forKey: "color and width");
```

I'm not getting any animation to occur.

Comment: what result does this code give?

Comment: What is not working? Include the error message and the expected result in an edit of your question (don't comment on comments, and don't include **Edit** or **Update** in your elaboration, we can see what changed from the edit history).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but for some reason calling:

```
color.fromValue = sender.layer.borderColor
```

doesn't work. The color isn't being read correctly or something. I changed it to:

```
let color = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor");
color.fromValue = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor;
color.toValue = UIColor.redColor().CGColor;
color.duration = 2;
color.repeatCount = 1;
sender.layer.addAnimation(color, forKey: "color and width");
```

And then things started working as expected.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4** `UIView` extension:

```
extension UIView {
  func animateBorderColor(toColor: UIColor, duration: Double) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    animation.fromValue = layer.borderColor
    animation.toValue = toColor.cgColor
    animation.duration = duration
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "borderColor")
    layer.borderColor = toColor.cgColor
  }
}
```

And then just use it by writing:

```
myView.animateBorderColor(toColor: .red, duration: 0.5)
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the same key name. You also forgot to add a border width and color to your layer before animating it. Try like this:

```
let color = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")

@IBAction func animateBorder(sender: AnyObject) {
    color.fromValue = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    color.toValue = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    color.duration = 2
    color.repeatCount = 1
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 2
    sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    sender.layer.addAnimation(color, forKey: "borderColor")
}
```

Comment: After playing with it some more. I think the problem is the fromColor. It's not reading the sender.layer.borderColor.

Comment: color.fromValue = sender.layer.borderColor also works for me here

Comment: The problem was the key name  forKey: "color and width". If you want to animate color and border you need to create one CABasicAnimation for each property (borderColor and borderWidth)

Comment: calling sender.layer.addAnimation(color, forKey: "color") works. It's when I change it to color.fromValue = sender.layer.borderColor that things break. I don't get it, but that's what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

**(Swift 5, Xcode 11, iOS 13)**

For anyone who is wanting to change border color and width at the same time, the following code is working for me & the animation looks very smooth. Maybe someone else knows of a way to combine both into one?

```
let borderColorAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
borderColorAnimation.fromValue = layer.borderColor
borderColorAnimation.toValue = toColor.cgColor
borderColorAnimation.duration = animationDuration
layer.add(borderColorAnimation, forKey: "borderColor")
layer.borderColor = toColor.cgColor

let borderWidthAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
borderWidthAnimation.fromValue = layer.borderWidth
borderWidthAnimation.toValue = toWidth
borderWidthAnimation.duration = animationDuration
layer.add(borderWidthAnimation, forKey: "borderWidth")
layer.borderWidth = toWidth
```

Comment: To combine animations we can use CAAnimationGroup. let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.animations = [colorsAnimation]
        animationGroup.duration = duration
        layer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "animation-group")

Answer (score 3):

I created a **Swift 4** function extension to `CALayer` for this, to which you can pass the starting and ending `UIColor`s as well as the duration for the animation:

```
extension CALayer {

func animateBorderColor(from startColor: UIColor, to endColor: UIColor, withDuration duration: Double) {
    let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    colorAnimation.fromValue = startColor.cgColor
    colorAnimation.toValue = endColor.cgColor
    colorAnimation.duration = duration
    self.borderColor = endColor.cgColor
    self.add(colorAnimation, forKey: "borderColor")
}
```

Note that for this to work, you should have already set a `borderWidth` and then call `animateBorderColor`:

```
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
yourView.layer.animateBorderColor(from: UIColor.green, to: UIColor.red, withDuration: 2.0)
```