# Swift Change circular border color with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, caanimation

I created a circular button using swift, what I am trying to do is changing the border color with animation

I used the following code :

```
let color = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
color.fromValue = UIColor.black.cgColor
color.toValue = UIColor.red.cgColor
color.duration = 1
color.repeatCount = 1
sender.layer.add(color, forKey: "color and width")
```

The border color is changing but it is not given the desire effect, it change the border color  all at once. What I would like to have as effect is like your drawing over the old color, to keep it simple ==> like a progress bar where u see the old color like fade away and be replaced by the new color.

Is there is any way to do that?

Thanks for helping.

Updating code

```
var storkeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

@IBOutlet weak var Mybut: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    storkeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    storkeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    storkeLayer.lineWidth = 2

    // Create a rounded rect path using button's bounds.

    storkeLayer.path = CGPath.init(roundedRect: Mybut.bounds, cornerWidth: Mybut.frame.width / 2 , cornerHeight: Mybut.frame.height / 2, transform: nil)


    // Add layer to the button
    Mybut.layer.addSublayer(storkeLayer)
}


 @IBAction func bytton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    storkeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    storkeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    storkeLayer.lineWidth = 2

    // Create a rounded rect path using button's bounds.

    storkeLayer.path = CGPath.init(roundedRect: Mybut.bounds, cornerWidth: Mybut.frame.width / 2 , cornerHeight: Mybut.frame.height / 2, transform: nil)


    // Add layer to the button
    sender.layer.addSublayer(storkeLayer)

    // Create animation layer and add it to the stroke layer.
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
    animation.toValue = CGFloat(1.0)
    animation.duration = 1
   animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

   // animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    storkeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "circleAnimation")



}
```

Comment: **Possible of duplication :**  
       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934948/how-to-animate-bordercolor-change-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: no it is not, as I said I want the stroke over animation and not changing the whole border at once

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can stroke the button's path using the following code snippet.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storkeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    storkeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    storkeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    storkeLayer.lineWidth = 2

    // Create a rounded rect path using button's bounds.
    storkeLayer.path = CGPath.init(roundedRect: sender.bounds, cornerWidth: 5, cornerHeight: 5, transform: nil) // same path like the empty one ...
    // Add layer to the button
    sender.layer.addSublayer(storkeLayer)

    // Create animation layer and add it to the stroke layer.
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = CGFloat(0.0)
    animation.toValue = CGFloat(1.0)
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    storkeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "circleAnimation")
}
```

This snippet creates something like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you @HAK, your code work on a standard UIbutton, in my case I have corner radius for circular button, how can I manage that? thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Increase the cornerWidth and cornerHeight in the CGPath.init method above to make it more circular.

Comment: ok thank you, I still have on little thing, when I load my view the Strokecolor is black when I click on the button to change the border color to red with the animation ==> the animation work perfectly fine, but the black color disappear instead of kind a fading. how can I resolve that? code updated above

Comment: I solve it by using a second storkeLayer. thank you man a million time

Comment: Thats amazing. Thank you! :)

Comment: thanks this is helpful, but I want to start animation from top left not from mid right height
how can we do that ?