# How to make circular loading animation color go from red to green as it loads

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, cashapelayer

I have implemented a circular loading animation exactly as in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ltwjDJaMk

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let center = view.center
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
     
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
    }
    
    @objc private func handleTap() {
 
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        
        basicAnimation.toValue = 1
        basicAnimation.duration = 2
        
        basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    }
}
```

When the animation happens I want the color of the circle to go from red towards green, if the circle is fully completed it should be green, if not then some color between red-green (depending on variable from the user-id). How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CAAnimation` to [animate color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53539593/526828) as well. So you can follow that link.

The part that is missing for you is to compute the `from` and `to` colors which need to be interpolated based on current values.

Assuming that your progress view will at some point have updated interface to have

```
var minimumValue: CGFloat = 0.0
var maximumValue: CGFloat = 100.0
var currentValue: CGFloat = 30.0 // 30%
```

then with those values you can compute a current progress, a value between `0` and `1` which should define color interpolation scale. A basic math to compute it should be:

```
let progress = (currentValue-maximumValue)/(minimumValue-maximumValue) // TODO: handle division by zero. Handle current value out of bounds.
```

With progress you can now interpolate any numeric value by using

```
func interpolate(_ values: (from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat), scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return values.from + (values.to - values.from)*scale
}
```

but a color is not a numeric value. In case of `CAAnimation` you should break it down to 4 numeric values as RGBA for consistency (at least I believe `CAAnimation` uses interpolation for color in RGBA space). Just as a note; in many cases it looks nicer when you interpolate in HSV space rather than RGB.

So interpolating a color should look something like this:

```
func rgba(_ color: UIColor) -> (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
    var r: CGFloat = 0.0
    var g: CGFloat = 0.0
    var b: CGFloat = 0.0
    var a: CGFloat = 0.0
    color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return (r, g, b, a)
}
func interpolate(_ values: (from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat), scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return values.from + (values.to - values.from)*scale
}
func interpolate(_ values: (from: UIColor, to: UIColor), scale: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    let startColorComponents = rgba(values.from)
    let endColorComponents = rgba(values.to)
    return .init(red: interpolate((startColorComponents.r, endColorComponents.r), scale: scale),
                 green: interpolate((startColorComponents.g, endColorComponents.g), scale: scale),
                 blue: interpolate((startColorComponents.b, endColorComponents.b), scale: scale),
                 alpha: interpolate((startColorComponents.a, endColorComponents.a), scale: scale))
}
```

These should be all components that you need for your animation and I hope it will be enough to put you on the right track. I personally like to have more control plus I like to avoid tools such as `CAAnimation` and even shape layers. So this is how I would accomplish your task:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var progressView: ProgressView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap)))
    }
    
    @objc private func onTap() {
        guard let progressView = progressView else { return }
        progressView.animateValue(to: .random(in: progressView.minimumValue...progressView.maximumValue), duration: 0.3)
    }


}

@IBDesignable class ProgressView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var minimumValue: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var maximumValue: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var value: CGFloat = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var colorAtZeroProgress: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var colorAtFullProgress: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    
    private var currentTimer: Timer?
    func animateValue(to: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval) {
        currentTimer?.invalidate()
        let startTime = Date()
        let startValue = self.value
        currentTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/60.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            let progress = CGFloat(max(0.0, min(Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)/duration, 1.0)))
            if progress >= 1.0 {
                // End of animation
                timer.invalidate()
            }
            self.value = startValue + (to - startValue)*progress
        })
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
         
        let progress = max(0.0, min((value-minimumValue)/(maximumValue-minimumValue), 1.0))
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)*0.5 - lineWidth*0.5
        let startAngle: CGFloat = -.pi*2.0
        let endAngle: CGFloat = startAngle + .pi*2.0*progress
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        
        
        
        let interpolatedColor: UIColor = {
            func rgba(_ color: UIColor) -> (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
                var r: CGFloat = 0.0
                var g: CGFloat = 0.0
                var b: CGFloat = 0.0
                var a: CGFloat = 0.0
                color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
                return (r, g, b, a)
            }
            func interpolate(_ values: (from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat), scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
                return values.from + (values.to - values.from)*scale
            }
            func interpolate(_ values: (from: UIColor, to: UIColor), scale: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
                let startColorComponents = rgba(values.from)
                let endColorComponents = rgba(values.to)
                return .init(red: interpolate((startColorComponents.r, endColorComponents.r), scale: scale),
                             green: interpolate((startColorComponents.g, endColorComponents.g), scale: scale),
                             blue: interpolate((startColorComponents.b, endColorComponents.b), scale: scale),
                             alpha: interpolate((startColorComponents.a, endColorComponents.a), scale: scale))
            }
            
            return interpolate((self.colorAtZeroProgress, self.colorAtFullProgress), scale: progress)
        }()
        
        interpolatedColor.setStroke()
        circularPath.lineCapStyle = .round
        circularPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        circularPath.stroke()
    }
    
    
}
```

Feel free to use it and modify it anyway you please.